# Regex match a sentence in a paragraph that contains new lines

Tags: javascript, regex, multiline

I basically have a paragraph of text in a html div. By clicking/activating a button, I would like to highlight a certain length of text. Hence, I would need to locate its index and add spans with class =highlight to them.

Hence, I would like to match a sentence in a innerHtml text such as:

```
var text = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog".
```

However, the paragraph might cut the sentence to multiple lines such as:

```
innerHTML = 
"The quick brown 
fox jumps over 
the lazy dog"
```

And I cannot "ulter" the innerHTML in anyway such as removing spaces/new lines from the text.

I cannot seem to think of or find the correct regex sequence to implement this.

This does not work:

```
var search_regexp = new RegExp(text, 'm');
innerHTML.search(search_regexp);
```

Comment: What do you want to do after match?

Comment: I basically have a paragraph of text in a html div. By clicking/activating a button, I would like to highlight a certain length of text. Hence, I would need to locate its index and add "<span>s" with class =highlight to them.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the help! Simon Brahan's answer did the trick. Unfortunately I couldn't display my upvote as it says I have less than 15 reputations with this new account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you're searching for any whitespace split between words (not just spaces) you need to replace the spaces in your search pattern with general whitespace tokens. This will work:

```
var regex = text.split(/\s+/).join('\\s+');
var search_regexp = new RegExp(text, 'm');
innerHTML.search(search_regexp);
```

The effect of the `split(/\s+/).join('\\s+')` is:

1. Split the input text on any amount of whitespace, producing an array of words,
2. Join the words with the `\s+` regex token, which matches one or more whitespace characters. this includes newlines and tabs.

Comment: No problem. Please tick the answer if it gives you what you need; helps other people with the same problem and gives me sweet internet points.

Answer (score 1):

You can `replace` *line-break* in both by *single space* and `match`.

```
var fnReplaceLR = ( str ) => str.replace(/\s+/g, " " ); //method to replace line-breaks and other consecutive multiple spaces with single space.
var text = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog";
var innerHTML = 
`The quick brown 
fox jumps over 
the lazy dog`;
var search_regexp = new RegExp( fnReplaceLR( text ) ); //no need for m modifier now
fnReplaceLR( innerHTML ).match( search_regexp ); //match the string
```

**Demo**

```js
var fnReplaceLR = (str) => str.replace(/\s+/g, " "); //method to replace line-breaks and other consecutive multiple spaces with single space.
var text = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog";
var innerHTML =
  `The quick brown 
    fox jumps over 
    the lazy dog`;
var search_regexp = new RegExp(fnReplaceLR(text)); //no need for m modifier now
var output = fnReplaceLR(innerHTML).match(search_regexp); //match the string
console.log(output);
```

Comment: Thanks @gurvinder372. Unfortunately, I cannot have to do this by not ultering (or "replacing") the inner HTML text. Is there another way to do it via a regex string?

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is how I would've done it.

Just split the text by `\n` and then join with `" "` to give it a singe line sentence format. Now you can use [.includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) to check if the text you want to match is the part of the other text or not

```js
var text = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog",
    stringWithBreakLines = `The quick brown
fox jumps over
the lazy dog
this is some additional
text in html`;
 
console.log(stringWithBreakLines.split("\n").join(" ").includes(text))
```

Comment: Thanks @George Bailey. Unfortunately, I cannot have to do this by not ultering (or "replacing") the inner HTML text. Is there another way to do it via a regex string?

Comment: nothing is being replaced here. You innerHTML will remain intact

Comment: `.split` does not change the original array. Instead, it returns a new array

Comment: ah I see. Thanks George. I think its my mistake to have left out the context of the problem too much. Basically I needed to have the index of where the sentence is in the original innerHTML so that I can locate the text and add "spans" to it. I have edited my problem statement..